# How I can I make jQuery go directly to <h2 id="id-name">?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make jQuery navigates directly (no animation need) to a id that I pass in a variable.

I have various marks like `id="content"`, `id="edit"`, `id="..."` that are `<h2>` titles. Doing validation with PHP I will output a variable like `var NAVIGATE_TO = <?php echo $where_failed;?>` and I want to move the website to that `id` position.

Like if I do `domain.tld/page#edit` or `#content` but with jQuery because when I load the page my PHP framework doesn't allow me to indicate the hash.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can set [`location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) to the `id` you need the browser to scroll to:

```
window.location.hash = '#edit';
```

Comment: Do you need the "#" in the hash string?

Comment: @Chris It's optional I believe, but getting `location.hash` will return a string including the `#`

Comment: ah, ok. I had assumed that the # would be considered a separator and thus not part of the hash itself. There's my little lesson for the day. :)

Answer (score 21):

In my experience the `window.location.hash` solution only works once. If you don't want to use the plugin you could try this:

```
var navigationFn = {
    goToSection: function(id) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(id).offset().top
        }, 0);
    }
}
```

and then call it like so (where `someID` is the ID of the element you wish to scroll to):

```
navigationFn.goToSection('#someID');
```

With this you can also vary the animation speed (I have it at 0) so that it is instant, but you could pass the value to the function so the code is reusable.

Comment: Pretty useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use the jquery [scrollto](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) plugin
then you can do it like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
      $(".topMenu").click(function() {
        $.scrollTo($("#edit"), { duration: 0});
      });
```

Answer (score 4):

I know it's an old question, but I thought it would be also a good solution if just want the element to be visible in the browsers view. (scroll without any animation).

```
var elem = document.getElementById("yourContent");
elem.scrollIntoView();
```

The above sample is taken from https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_scrollintoview.asp

Comment: This should be default answer. Just plain JS with no tricks, hashtags, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**the question is for "jQuery"**

**with jQuery**
@Patrick 's answer will be right and here is the example without function:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#id").offset().top}, 0);
```

**with javascript:**
@Yi Jiang 's answer is javascript based

```
window.location.hash = '#idWithOrWithoutHashSign';
```

@Yusufbek answer works.
but why create variable?
instead:

```
document.getElementById("idWithoutHashSign").scrollIntoView();
```

also check difference with "smooth";

```
document.getElementById("idWithoutHashSign").scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
```