# Display reset/reveal button for collapsing header

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the collapsing header described here http://codepen.io/cbracco/pen/corFl

I'd like to enhance it with the following feature:
When the user has scrolled the content area all over the header I'd like to display a "reset" button that pushes the content area back to its initial position and reveals the header fully again.

I guess at least for the reset, I'd have to use `javascript` (or the CSS checkbox trick maybe?). Could the "reset" button made visible purely by using CSS or would I have to use `window.onScroll` to detect scrolling of the content area and display the button myself via `javascript`?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an element with an id at the top of the page (i.e. `<span id="top">`), and then use Javascript to scroll to that element.

```
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    window.location.hash = "#top";
});
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193167/how-i-can-i-make-jquery-go-directly-to-h2-id-id-name) SO question.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll to top can easily be done without javascript:

```
<div id="top">lorem ipsum</a>
<a href="#top">go to top</a>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZBXyg

If you however want to smoothly scroll to the top, then I'd suggest to use this neat little snippet of jquery:

```
$('#top').click(function() {
  if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
    var target = $(this.hash);
    history.pushState({}, '', target.selector);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
    if (target.length) {
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
      }, 1000);
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZJmyP

To reveal the "reset" button based on how much the user has scrolled, you might want to utilize the window.onscroll listener and then check the scrollTop value
With native javascript:

```
window.onscroll = function(){
    console.log(document.body.scrollTop)
}
```

With jQuery

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    console.log($(window).scrollTop());
});
```